# Unix determine if a file is empty

Tags: unix, if-statement, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to make a script that will check to see if there is any tyext within a file. I have developed the following script. I have made it check to see if there is exactly 2 arguments, see if the file exists, but I am having trouble checking the file for text within it. The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#check if number of arguments are 2

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Does not equal two arguments"
    echo "Usage $0 inputfile outputfile"
    exit 1
fi

#check if input file exists

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "$1 not found!"
    exit 1
fi

#Check if input file is null
#This next block of code is where the issue is
if [ grep -q $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1 must have text within the file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test's "-s" option checks if the file is empty -- see [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test).  So your last chunk would become

```
#Check if input file is null
#This next block of code is where the issue is
if [ ! -s $1 ]; then
    echo "$1 must have text within the file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using stat

stat -c %s filename